# How to detect negative values in a <td> of table in html?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have a table in html, I am using Tangle framework to make the values look dynamic of that table.
What I want is to place a check on a specific `<td>` if its numeric value ever gets **negative**, the entire `<tr>` of that particular `<td>` should change its background color to **Red**.
Can this be done using java script or some simple lines of code may solve this problem?
Please help me doing this.

Comment: Yes, it can be done (easily), what's your (relevant) HTML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
     td.negative { color : red; }
    </style>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    function MakeNegative() {
        TDs = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
        for (var i=0; i<TDs.length; i++) {
                var temp = TDs[i];
                if (temp.firstChild.nodeValue.indexOf('-') == 0) temp.className = "negative";
            }
    }
    //-->
    </script>
</head>
<body>
 <table id="mytable">
  <caption>Some Financial Stuff</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr><th scope="col">Date</th><th scope="col">Money is good</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr><td>2006-05-01</td><td>19.95</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2006-05-02</td><td>-54.54</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2006-05-03</td><td>34.45</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2006-05-04</td><td>88.00</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2006-05-05</td><td>22.43</td></tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  <!--
   MakeNegative();
  //-->
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Looking for a dash or minus sign at any position and then checking, if it's at the beginning, is kind of pointless. If you expect it at the beginning, look for it at the beginning: `...nodeValue[0] === "-"`

Comment: Since `nodeValue` doesn't normalise prefixing white-space, you should ignore it explicitly: `/^\s*-/.test(...nodeValue)`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0],
    cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td'),
    hasNegative = 'hasNegative',
    text = 'textContent' in document ? 'textContent' : 'innerText', num = 0;

for (var i = 0, len = cells.length; i < len; i++) {
    num = parseFloat(cells[i][text]);
    if (Math.abs(num) !== num) {
        cells[i].parentNode.className += ' hasNegative';
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/teJEY/1/).

The rather bizarre means to determine negativity was a result of my previous, perhaps naive, check [failing to differentiate between `0` and `-0`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/teJEY/) (though I'm not quite sure whether negative-zero would pass, or fail, your criteria).